# Why are resistors and capacitors placed in the feedback network of op-amp voltage followers?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, resistors, feedback

I've been looking at a circuit that has an amplifier cascade used in a servo amplifier. In this amplifier cascade, there are blocks to control the gain and blocks to control the roll-off frequency of the servo amplifier. I've been having issues understanding the roll-off frequency blocks. I've included a schematic of one of the blocks isolated from the rest of the circuit for simplicity.

[image]

From what I understand, the RC circuit formed by R1 and C1 acts as the low-pass filter while the op-amp acts as a voltage follower that tracks the output of the RC circuit.

What I don't understand is: what is the use of R2 and C2 in the feedback path of the voltage follower? In a section of the description of the circuit, the author mentions that capacitors such as C2 are to ensure that the Bode plot of the servo amplifier is flat with respect to frequency out to the -3dB point/roll-off frequency of the amplifier. So also, how do the resistor and capacitor effect the flatness of the response of the amplifier?

Comment: The circuit shown is likely to reduce ringing at the output.  Depending on the op amp and the load, overshoot, ringing and even oscillation can occur.

Comment: @user263983 how could that circuit possibly have a gain of 6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The author is correct in that the capacitor, if its value is chosen correctly in combination with the parallel feedback resistor, will improve the frequency response of the servo amp. To see why this is, first consider what happens if you have a capacitive load at the output of the opamp. Generally, such a capacitor produces a pole due to the finite output resistance of the opamp. If this pole is low enough in frequency, then the open-loop gain of the opamp will exhibit additional phase shift near the unity gain frequency. When put in a unity feedback configuration, the opamp will have less phase margin and as a result, may exhibit peaking in the frequency domain and ringing in the time domain (among other potential undesirable behavior).

Now where could this potential capacitance at the output come from? Well, when you configure an opamp for unity gain, you connect its output to the inverting input. But that inverting input has it's own input capacitance. So in effect, the input capacitance of the amplifier becomes the aforementioned problematic load capacitance. If we were to just stick a resistor in the feedback path the problem would be exacerbated, since that resistance could be thought of as being in series with the output resistance of the opamp, thereby lowering the pole frequency and decreasing phase margin.

That's where the additional feedback capacitance comes into play. The simplest equivalent circuit approximation we can make for the inverting input is a parallel RC network connected to ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Ermp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If we use a feedback network with a parallel RC network, we will effective have two parallel RC networks in series with the output resistance of the opamp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7O5HH.png)</sup>

Note that I included \$R_3\$ as the effective output resistance of the opamp.

If we choose \$R_1C_1 = R_2C_2\$, then you can show that the transfer function from Node 1 to Node 2 is simply a voltage division, \$\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}\$, which is completely independent of frequency. You can think of this network as a resistive voltage divider in parallel with a capacitive voltage divider. If both voltage division ratios are equal, then the response is flat over frequency.

Now you may ask, "What about \$R_3\$, the opamp output resistance?" That was the original problem, after all. And it is still a problem, however a lesser problem. You can see that the effective capacitance that \$R_3\$ now sees is approximately the series combination of \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$, which is strictly less than the original \$C_1\$. So the pole seen at the opamp output is now higher in frequency and thus contributes less to the phase margin of the feedback loop. So if component values are chosen reasonably, we can expect that the closed-loop frequency response should be flatter out to its bandwidth with less ringing in the time domain.

The main trade-off you make with this approach is dropping the gain due to the feedback voltage division. However if you only need to make a small increase in the pole frequency to improve the phase margin, the gain can stay fairly close to unity.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. The values are orders of magnitude off. R1 is probably around 1 Tohm and C1 is 3 pF.

Comment: If you wanted to select values for R2 and C2, how would you find the values for R1 and C1 based on the chosen op-amp? Would it be from the quoted "Input Impedance" section of the op-amp datasheet? Or, is there another way to determine the inverting input impedance?

Comment: @tobalt Apologies, I didn't realize that the opamp in question was JFET input. In this case, we would take \$R_1\rightarrow\infty\$. The feedback parallel RC now acts similar to a lead-lag compensator by inserting a zero in the feedback response. The zero frequency is lower than the pole frequency created by \$R_2\$, \$C_2\$, and \$C_1\$, which ultimately provides positive phase to the loop gain between the zero and pole frequencies. When \$R_1\$ is small enough like I assumed in my answer, you can choose the zero frequency to fall exactly on pole frequency, causing perfect cancellation.

Comment: @everettAdams If the datasheet told you both the input resistance and capacitance (which is does in this case), then yes, you could use those. However, I didn't realize you were using a JFET input opamp which has very high input resistance. In that case, you cannot exactly perform the strategy I mentioned in the answer, but you can come close by creating a low frequency zero that provides additional positive phase to compensate the loop gain and provide more phase margin.